# depth first search algorithm

Tags: c++, search, depth-first-search

I want to reach  node Y of this tree but this code  traversal whole tree. what changes should i do to achieve my goal? how to show traveled path at each step of traversal? I use depth first search.
thanks for any help.

```
class Graph
{
int V;    // No. of vertices
list<int> *adj;    
void DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]);  
public:
Graph(int V);   
void addEdge(int v, int w);  
void DFS(int v);  
};
Graph::Graph(int V)
{
this->V = V;
adj = new list<int>[V];
}
void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
}
 void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[])
{
visited[v] = true;
cout << v << " ";
list<int>::iterator i;
for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
    if (!visited[*i])
        DFSUtil(*i, visited);
}
void Graph::DFS(int v)
{
bool *visited = new bool[V];
for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    visited[i] = false;
DFSUtil(v, visited);
}
int main()
{
Graph g(25);
g.addEdge(0, 1);
g.addEdge(0, 2);
//...
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Copied homework from someone? :(

Comment: @Starl1ght from here possibly: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/depth-first-traversal-for-a-graph/

Comment: "I know how to do ABC. How can I do A?" Where did you get that code? If you wrote it yourself, the answer should be trivial

Answer (score 0):

Graph::DFSUtil should return a "found" flag, and a list of traversed nodes so far, which can be extended every time a "found==true" is detected.